# Variable in Jquery not defined in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 pieces of code, one jQuery which checks the value of an `input` field and then takes this value a manipulates the CSS relatively. I have some vanilla Javascript and I was looking to use my jQuery to manipulate the JS as the jQuery is outside code block. How would I able to use the variables inside the jQuery in my vanilla Javascript?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var inputNo = (10 / val);
    if (val > 0) {
      $(".orb").addClass("rotating");
      $('.rotating').css("animation", "rotating " + inputNo + "s linear infinite");
    } else {
      $(".orb").removeClass("rotating");
    }
    console.log(inputNo);
  });
});

function init() {
  ctx.shadowColor = "#57e0c1";
  ctx.shadowBlur = inputNo;
  for (var i = 0; i <= totalTentacles - 1; i++) {
    lines[lines.length] = new Line();
  }
  animate();
}
init();
```

Comment: What you want to do

Comment: why you are separating those parts? Just move the `init()` inside the `ready()` and move the `inputNo` declaration out of `change`

Comment: You could pass `inputNo` as an argument to `init()`, although I'm not sure why you'd ever want to do this as `init()` only runs once on load and wouldn't have any need of the `inputNo` value...?

Answer (score 1):

The variable is scoped within the `$('input').change` function. This essentially means it disappears when the function ends. If you want it to be accessible to multiple function, you need to initialize it outside the function.

Eg.

```
var inputNo = 0; // declared outside function block

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    inputNo = (10 / val);
        if (val > 0) {
            $(".orb").addClass("rotating");
            $('.rotating').css("animation","rotating "+ inputNo +"s linear infinite");
        }
        else {
            $(".orb").removeClass("rotating");
        }
        console.log(inputNo);
  });
});


function init() {
  ctx.shadowColor = "#57e0c1";
  ctx.shadowBlur = inputNo;
  for (var i = 0; i <= totalTentacles - 1; i++) {
    lines[lines.length] = new Line();
  }
  animate();
}
init();
```

Note, there are deeper issues in your code however than simple variable scoping. For example, your init function will need to be called again within the change function if you want to update the shadow-blur on change as well.. so replace `console.log(inputNo);` with another `init();` call.

Comment: Thank you for the help, this is great however val which is also defined inside the .ready function needs to be accessed by this code.. I have tried putting everything in the .ready function but this dose not work..